# How to protect my PHP API's security acessed via Ajax with OAuth2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, oauth

I currently have an `cross-origin` `ajax` application that consumes some personal `API's` that I made.

I want to secure it so only my application can use the `api`.

I did some search and found [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/). I followed [this step-by-step](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/) using `php`, but my app is build using `ajax` requests, so I found this [OAuth JS Library](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso) to authenticate using `ajax`, but I don't understand how to use it, can someone give some simple examples? I'm really a beginner in using OAuth.

My code is more or less like this:

My .js file for requests:
**myrequests.js**

```
function someRequest(parameter1){

    return $.ajax({
        url:'http:/www.mysite.com/myapis/customapi.php?callback=?',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        data:{p1:parameter1}
    })
        .done(function(data){
        console.log("Done!");
    })
        .fail(function(data,textStatus,errorThrown){
        console.error(data,textStatus,errorThrown);

    })
}
```

My api file in server: **customapi.php**

```
  <?php
    include "dbConnect.php";
    header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8');

    $p = $_GET['p1']; er

    $myquery = "SELECT name, adress from table1 WHERE name = :p";
    $sql = $pdo->prepare($myquery);


    $sql->bindValue(":p",$p,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->fetchAll(); 


    $data['d'] = $result;
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rely on sessions/cookies - i.e. that your PHP API backend reads - as it's essentially the same domain (i guess) for both front-end and back-end.

You can create a cookie with salt every time someone visits your page and you read that from your API php script. This means of course that anyone that has a cookie from your site can read your API but that would be the same if the visit your side.

If needed you can create the cookie only for users who has logged in on your site.

Comment: My application is `cross-origin`, the back-end and frond-end are in different domains. The `js` file is in place and the `php` `api` is in a different domain. I can't use cookies; plus, I wanted a more secure aproach like OAuth.